# How to create additional terminal in linux screen from bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-screen

In screen, you can press `ctrl+a c` to create new terminal inside the same screen session. Now I have to automate this activity and do the same from my bash script:

```
dbus-launch screen
finch
ctrl+a c <--------- HOW TO CHANGE THAT LINE?
python myscript
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -S <session> -X screen <command to run in the new window>
```

You should add the session tag when you first create the screen session.

Example:

```
# Create screen session named myscreen and detach.
dbus-launch screen -S myscreen -d -m
# Do something
# ...
# Create a new screen window and launch python on it.
screen -S myscreen -X screen python -v
```

Comment: And then what? Can I see some working example?

Comment: It's marked as duplicate now, you have an example in the linked answer too.